# JTable cellRenderer doesnt change just desingated cells

Tags: java, jtable, cellrenderer

Here is a code part of my project. 
I am  try to change the color of desingated cells. But when i try it, all cells' color changing. Why is that ?
Thanks.

```
private class cellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
      if(row==column){
          cell.setBackground(Color.yellow);
      }     
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732005/trying-to-color-specific-cell-in-jtable-gettablecellrenderercomponent-overide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to restore the original color.

```
private class cellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    Color originalColor = null;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

      Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);


       if (originalColor == null) {
           originalColor = cell.getBackground();
      }

      if(row==column){
          cell.setBackground(Color.yellow);
      } else {
          cell.setBackground(originalColor);
      }

      return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best to take `isSelected` into account as well, ie don't set any background is it is `true`. Most often the standard background color, is `table.getBackground()`.